# Git Error when trying to change core editor

Tags: git

I made a mistake on setting up my core editor now I cannot change it...tried to get it to change to TextMate and to correctly change it to sublime but just keep getting the same error as seen below...How can I fix this?  I really just want to get my core editor to be TextMate.

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ RFreude$ git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"

Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ RFreude$ git config --global -e
```

> sublime text 3 -w: sublime: command not found
>
> error: There was a problem with the editor 'sublime text 3 -w'."

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the symlink `subl` is not broken?

Comment: It looks like it is...what can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the link is broken, you can try creating the symlink again using:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

More details [here](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to revert that edit using

```
➜  git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

and check if that works fine

```
➜  git config --global --edit
```

Comment: Nope...same error, I've searched everywhere trying to figure out a way to clear that out and now luck.  I'll keep looking.